# Spring boot how to customise deserialisation

Tags: java, spring, jackson

There are plenty of topics on this subject but none seem to help with what I'm trying to do. I have JSON API Spec'ed String payloads coming into `Controllers` but I'd like to intercept the incoming payload and deserialise it in a custom manner.

So code to explain:

```
@PostMapping("/steaks")
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody String payload) {
    // JsonTransformService is a custom service which converts the JSON API Spec string into a Steak POJO
    final Steak steak = jsonTransformService.read(Steak.class, payload);

    // [...] logic to do with a Steak
}
```

What I'd like to have is

```
@PostMapping("/steaks")
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Steak steak) {
    // [...] logic to do with a Steak
}
```

However at the moment I can't do that because the payload isn't a straight match for deserialising.

So, I've tried extending `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and overriding the `read` method but that didn't work because consuming the `inputMessage` closes the stream.

What's the right way to handle this?

**Edit**

Attempting to use a converter as suggested but it's being ignored by the `Controller`

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SteakConverter implements Converter<String, Steak> {

    private final JsonTransformService jsonTransformService;

    public SteakConverter(JsonTransformService jsonTransformService) {
        this.jsonTransformService = jsonTransformService;
    }

    @Override
    public Steak convert(String value) throws IOException {
        log.info("converting {}", value);

        return jsonTransformService.read(Steak.class, value);
    }
}
```

And adjusted the `Controller`

```
public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Steak steak) {}
```

Comment: Just use a [converter](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder).

Comment: I wasn't aware of converters... How do I register a converter in the controller? I've written one but it's being ignored.

Comment: You should only need to declare it as a bean - if it's not being triggered then Spring doesn't think you have the right types.

Comment: Based on my code examples do you see anything I've missed? Still just being skipped over;

Comment: I would suggest debugging into the conversion subsystem to see what Spring is up to - I can't see a clear problem with what you have posted. You're sure that the converter is picked up and created during component scanning?