# Spring boot 2.0 custom converter being ignored

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've either completely miss-understood converters, or all the examples/blogs/docs I've found are assuming I've done a step... My understanding is that when I post a `String`, the converter will pick it up and give the `Controller` a POJO instead.

The problem I have is the converter is never being called.

The payload coming into the controller is a standard JSON API string

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "attributes":{  
         "created-date":null,
      },
      "type":"steaks"
   }
}
```

The converter:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class SteakConverter implements Converter<String, Steak> {

    @Override
    public Steak convert(String value) {
        log.info("converter value {}", value);
        return new Steak.builder().build();
    }
}
```

The controller:

```
@Slf4j
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class SteakController {

    @PostMapping("/steaks")
    public ResponseEntity<String> create(@RequestBody Steak steak) {

    }

}
```

From reading all the blogs and docs I can find this should be all that's needed. However I've also tried manually registering with the following:

```
@Slf4j
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        log.info("Converter registered");
        registry.addConverter(new SteakConverter());
    }

}
```

This is called during application startup.

The only thing I can think of is that the converter/controller doesn't think the payload is in fact a String, so is ignoring it?

How can I debug this, or just make it work?

Here is a [working sample application](https://github.com/peavers/converter-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoApplication.java) that shows my problem.

Cheers

Comment: You should make your converter a bean. Add `@Component` to it's type declaration, instead of `@Configuration` and inject it into FormatterRegistry.

Comment: Done and done, still being skipped.

Comment: Remove `@EnableWebMvc` from WebConfig, as this annotation disables Spring Boot Auto Configuration.

Comment: Done and still no change...

Comment: Converter will be used only to convert form field, not payload.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the docs for that? Everything I've seen has people using them on `@RequestBody` etc

Comment: From what I know Converter is used for form field String to Object conversion, it won't go deep into JSON object. Can you share where did you see such solution? Can you show your Steak class?

Comment: Hmm you might be right. Looking at http://www.baeldung.com/spring-type-conversions it's all `@RequestParam`. The rabbit hole started at my previous SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51051173/spring-boot-how-to-customise-deserialisation

Comment: What you need is to data binding, i.e. bind your payload to Java object. You may find this blog useful -> https://springframework.guru/processing-json-jackson/

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm after. I already have my logic to convert my `String payload` into the POJO correctly. I just want it to happen before it hits the controller, not after.

Comment: It is not Payload conversion, but request parameter conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174133/discussion-between-chris-turner-and-fg78nc).

Comment: no answers, damn... and here I am in 2022 hoping for a better world